# How to check if a field contains a string of numbers or an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, netsuite, suitescript

A  user can enter into a textbox either individual serial numbers, i.e. 1,2,3,4,5, or scan QR codes that output into a format of [460, 3], [123,321], [900,123].

What I need to do is validate the field to check whether a QR code is scanned or if a user entered in individual numbers. Assume that it's either one format or the other - it can't be both.

Currently I have this as a filter:

```
if(serialnumbers[0] != '['({
   //code for individual numbers
}
else{ //code for qr code arrays
}
```

Basically, I'm just checking if the textbox value starts with a bracket to see if its a list of numbers or a list of arrays, but I'm wondering if there is a better way to check this

Comment: Could scenario in which to use typeof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a single Regular Expression.

I have posted a relevant RegEx for you to explore and learn from here: http://regexr.com/3f4au

Used in code, this would be:

```
var individualCheck = /^(\d+)$|^((\d+,)+(\d+))$/;
var qrCheck = /^\[(\d+\,\d+)\]((\,\s*\[(\d+\,\d+)\])*)$/;

if (serialnumbers.match(individualCheck)){
    console.log("Individual Numbers Style");
    // code for individual numbers
} else if (serialnumbers.match(qrCheck)) { 
    console.log("QR Codes Style");
    //code for qr code arrays
} else {
    console.log("Validation failed");
    //code for invalid input
}
```

Or a JSFiddle for you: [https://jsfiddle.net/kitkit/5Lxmz6dy/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/kitkit/5Lxmz6dy/1/)

Comment: thanks for the demo. It works if only one QR code is scanned, but if multiple are scanned then it won't work

Comment: Apologies Chris - I didn't originally realise that you wanted to also allow for an unlimited list of QR codes. I have updated my answer to allow for this with an enhanced QRCode check, and also updated the RegExr and JSFiddle links.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you wouldn't be able to use typeof.
This is what I would do here:

```
if(typeof serialnumbers != 'string'){
    //code for qr code arrays
}
else{
    //code for individual numbers
}
```

My Fiddle goes more in depth, check it out!
https://jsfiddle.net/zkqd1bre/3/

Comment: The field is a textbox so it is always a string. I already have a way of converting the string into an array of numbers or an array of arrays, but can't seem to find a better way to check whether its a string of numbers or string of arrays first.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(serialnumbers.substr(0, 1) != '['){
    //code for individual numbers
}
```

You can see more on this function here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp

Answer (score 0):

you could do it with this regex, which is more straigtforward than it first looks as it is just one alternation:

```
/^((\d+(,\s*|$))+|(\[\d+,\s*\d+\](,\s*|$))+)$/.test(input)
```

breakdown in english:

-from start of string `^`, consume:

-(first part of main alternation `|`) comma separated list of *number* `(\d+(,\s*|$))+`

-**OR** (second part of alternation) comma separated list of *[number, number]* `(\[\d+,\s*\d+\](,\s*|$))+`

-followed immediately by end of input `$`.

https://regex101.com/r/Sr1zES/3